# How to install postgressql-server

Tags: ruby, rails

For `ruby` development on Heroku I need to use `postgresql`, but when I do bundle install I see this message:

```
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.   
checking for libpq-fe.h... no   Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```

Comment: PGSQL is available in the official repositories. Here's the [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/postgresql.html). IN this case, you need to do at least `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install the PostgreSQL server: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

And install the lib necessary for the pg gem:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

It should work after that.